# Rack cors error in full stack application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-fullstack

I am using react for the front end and Ruby on Rails for the back end. I am using version 2.6.1 for ruby on rails.
When I started my application I am getting an error saying...

"Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/profile' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: So have you tried configuring CORS?

Comment: Please explain, not sure what to do at all with that